# Finding the initial velocity using calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives, physics

I throw a stone at 20 degree, when the stone falls to the ground, it reaches 100m further.
Using CALCULUS methods, find the initial velocity of the stone.

Comment: i got 39.05 as final answer with physics formula, but dunno how to use calculus to solve this :/

Comment: The answer is correct, under the usual assumptions (airless planet with same acceleration due to gravity as Earth). For calculus solution, need *some* Physics concepts, such as vertical, horizontal component of velocity.

Comment: by the way, I'm just wandering, what will the graph of velocity as a function of time look like?

Answer (score 1):

The calculus part in this is taking the derivative of $\vec{r}(t)$,which is $\dot{\vec{r}}(t)=\vec{v}(t)$ (the dot above r means derivative with respect to $t$). Most of the used concepts in this example are from physics, though.

Somewhere in your calculation, you must have $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, which represent the position of the stone dependent on time. Assume that the initial time when you throw the stone is $t=0$. Because $\vec{r}(t)=(x(t),y(t))$, $\vec{v}(t)=\dot{\vec{r}}(t)=(\dot x(t),\dot y(t))$, and thus $\vec{v}(0)=(\dot x(0),\dot y(0))$.

The last formula is the "calculus" part of the calculation.